# How to get the position of a draggable object

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, position

I'm trying to get the `x` and `y` of the draggable object using jQuery.

The scenario is, I'm dragging and dropping an object onto another object and want to get the position of the drag & drop object.

***Edit: Now I can get the position of the object but I need more:***

Here is what I've tried:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $('#draggable').draggable({
        drag: function() {
            var offset = $(this).offset();
            var xPos = offset.left;
            var yPos = offset.top;
            $(this).text('x: ' + xPos + 'y: ' + yPos);
        }
    });

    $("#droppable").droppable({
        drop: function(event, ui) {
            $(this)
                .addClass("ui-state-highlight")
                .find("p")
                .html("Dropped!");
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Now I can get the position of the draggable object but I need it to be resizable and in addition to getting `x,y` of the draggable, I also need the size of it.

Comment: I've just answered what I *thought* your question was. But re-reading, I'm not so sure. Could you clarify what you want to find out? As I was *assuming* you wanted to have a continuous update of the `x`/`y` position of the object that you're dragging...I might not have answered your question at all.

Comment: David, actually what I need is a bit more complicated but you might do great help. What I want to do is to put a draggable object and a droppable image in a panel and drag the draggable object on the image and get the position of where it was dropped. I'll also need the draggable object to be resizable and get the size of it at the end too :) thank you

Answer (score 80, accepted):

You can use the `drag` event:

```
$('#dragThis').draggable({
    drag: function() {
        var offset = $(this).offset();
        var xPos = offset.left;
        var yPos = offset.top;
        $('#posX').text('x: ' + xPos);
        $('#posY').text('y: ' + yPos);
    }
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://www.jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/DGbT3/).

This demo brought to you by the [`drag event`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#event-drag), and the methods [`offset()`](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) and [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/).

---

**Edited** in response to comment from OP, to original question:

> David, actually what I need is a bit more complicated but you might do great help. What I want to do is to put a draggable object and a droppable image in a panel and drag the draggable object on the image and get the position of where it was dropped. I'll also need the draggable object to be resizable and get the size of it at the end too :) thank you

...uh, *whoah*...

I *think* this sort of covers the basics of what's asked for:

```
$('#dragThis').draggable( {
    containment: $('body'),
    drag: function() {
        var offset = $(this).offset();
        var xPos = offset.left;
        var yPos = offset.top;
        $('#posX').text('x: ' + xPos);
        $('#posY').text('y: ' + yPos);
    },
    stop: function() {
        var finalOffset = $(this).offset();
        var finalxPos = finalOffset.left;
        var finalyPos = finalOffset.top;

        $('#finalX').text('Final X: ' + finalxPos);
        $('#finalY').text('Final X: ' + finalyPos);
    },
    revert: 'invalid'
});

$('#dropHere').droppable({
    accept: '#dragThis',
    over: function() {
        $(this).animate({
            'border-width': '5px',
            'border-color': '#0f0'
        }, 500);
        $('#dragThis').draggable('option', 'containment', $(this));
    }
});
```

[Updated JS Fiddle demo](http://www.jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/DGbT3/1/).

[Newly-updated JS Fiddle demo, featuring `revert: invalid`](http://www.jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/DGbT3/2/), so dropping the draggable div anywhere *but* the droppable div will cause the draggable to animate back to its starting position. If that'd be appreciated. Or desired at all...

To address the requirement for the `draggable` object to be `resizable` as well, I don't think that this is possible, since both `draggable()` and `resizable()` respond to the *same* interaction. It may be possible, in some way, but it's currently beyond my ken, I'm afraid.

---

**Edited** to add in the 'height/width' requirement, and also to tidy up a few things and improve the CSS. That said:

#### HTML:

```
<div id="dragThis">
    <ul>
        <li id="posX">x: <span></span></li>
        <li id="posY">y: <span></span></li>
        <li id="finalX">Final X: <span></span></li>
        <li id="finalY">Final Y: <span></span></li>
        <li id="width">Width: <span></span></li>
        <li id="height">Height: <span></span></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="dropHere"></div>
```

#### CSS:

```
#dragThis {
    width: 8em;
    height: 8em;
    padding: 0.5em;
    border: 3px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 0 1em 1em 1em;
    background-color: #fff;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}

#dragThis span {
    float: right;
}

#dragThis span:after {
    content: "px";
}

li {
    clear: both;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    line-height: 1.2em;
}

#dropHere {
    width: 12em;
    height: 12em;
    padding: 0.5em;
    border: 3px solid #f90;
    border-radius: 1em;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

#### jQuery:

```
$('#dragThis').draggable({
    containment: $('body'),
    drag: function() {
        var offset = $(this).offset();
        var xPos = offset.left;
        var yPos = offset.top;
        $('#posX > span').text(xPos);
        $('#posY > span').text(yPos);
    },
    stop: function() {
        var finalOffset = $(this).offset();
        var finalxPos = finalOffset.left;
        var finalyPos = finalOffset.top;

        $('#finalX > span').text(finalxPos);
        $('#finalY > span').text(finalyPos);
        $('#width > span').text($(this).width());
        $('#height > span').text($(this).height());
    },
    revert: 'invalid'
});

$('#dropHere').droppable({
    accept: '#dragThis',
    over: function() {
        $(this).animate({
            'border-width': '5px',
            'border-color': '#0f0'
        }, 500);
        $('#dragThis').draggable('option', 'containment', $(this));
    }
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo, of the above](http://www.jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/DGbT3/3/).

Comment: Ca you please help me with the rest if you have time? Thanks David

Comment: @David, can you please make it resizable too :) Thank you! Greatly appreciated

Comment: @Pabuc, if you look at the final paragraph the answer is, sadly, "no, I can't." Mainly because both `draggable()` and `droppable()` respond to the same user-actions, and I can't find a way to differentiate between which plugin/method should be invoked. Possibly by nesting spans, or divs, within the element, but...I'm not convinced. Sorry =(

Comment: Okay then I have to find a workaround and the first one I can think of is, since I'll be letting users to enter text into the draggable object, Do you think that it is possible to get the length of the text and resize the draggable object?

Comment: @Pabuc: yep; that shouldn't be too hard. Though I'd suggest searching to see if others have already asked the question (or a similar question that you could build from) or, failing that, ask another question. I'm running out of space to add more information to this answer and, honestly, we're drifting a long way from your *original* question... =)

Comment: Thank you David. I've posted another question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4903863/resizable-droppable-object-in-jquery-possible . This might interest you too :) Thank you again

Comment: @Pabuc, so I see =) I think, however, that I'll concede defeat for this evening and go to bed...been a long day! Good luck with the next question (forgive my edit there, but I felt it might be useful for others to see this question as well) =D Oh, and incidentally I've shown (in my final edit as of writing) how to retrieve the `width` and `height` of the draggable object.

Comment: I know this is more than a year old, but it did exactly what i needed and in the easiest way. Thanks.

Comment: @AustinBest: age doesn't necessarily invalidate a solution! And you're very welcome, I'm glad that, even after quite a time, I was able to help out! =)

Comment: @SameeraPrasadJayasinghe: you’re very welcome indeed!

Answer (score 15):

You can try one of these:

```
$(this).position()
```

or

```
$(this).offset()
```

The `.position()` method allows us to retrieve the current position of an element relative to the offset parent. Contrast this with `.offset()`, which retrieves the current position relative to the document.

From http://api.jquery.com/position/

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stackoverflow! It's worth taking a read of the [Stackoverflow Markdown help page](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help/) to get a feel for how to format your answers (for code blocks, and such) =)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the width output with .resizable() and stop event. Try adding this:

```
$('#dragThis').resizable({ handles: "e, w",      
      stop: function(event, ui) {
        var width = ui.size.width;
        var height = ui.size.height;
    $('#width > span').text($(this).width());
    $('#height > span').text($(this).height());
      }
   });
```