# Resizable, draggable object in jquery. Possible?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, draggable, resizable

I want to have an object which is both resizable and draggable. I'll need:

- X
- Y
- Size

of the object.

Is this possible?

There is an example on http://www.jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/DGbT3/1/ which gets the x and y of the draggable object. How can I also make it resizable?

Thanks

---

It's worth adding that this question is related to, and built on, this previous question: [How to get the position of a draggable object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4903530/how-to-get-the-position-of-a-draggable-object/4903560#4903560)

Comment: Don't you mean draggable, since dragging and resizing needs the same mouse movement and events (click, drag), but a droppable item just sits there waiting for something to dragged atop, and you can resize it anytime, I think.

Comment: thank you inti, it should be draggable as you mentioned.

Comment: @Mahesh - Care to help instead of telling it is possible?

Comment: Yes! would be the answer to this question

Comment: @Pabuc: Your question is framed in a way that the answer that I gave answers your question.

Comment: Yes, I am currently able to do as shown here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4903530/how-to-get-the-position-of-a-draggable-object/4903560#4903560 need to add resizable property to it.

Comment: @Pabuc Do you know about this: http://jqueryui.com/demos/resizable/ ?

Comment: Seriously? The question is, indeed, 'is it possible?' But could we assume that the OP **means** 'how can this be implemented?' instead?

Comment: Sime yes. Please have a look at the link that I've added into my question. What I need is to make the draggable object also resizable and get the size of it. Adding resizable() infront of draggable() doesn't work..

Comment: @David Yes, that is obviously what we all assume. But I like to innocently answer the initial question first to get the rapport going `:)`

Comment: So everybody knows how to do it yet no one cares to point out how?

Comment: @Pabuc I'm sure that somebody is working on this issue as we speak. I'm not familiar with jQuery UI but I'll look into it too.

Comment: @Sime, I must confess that I did have a lol-moment when I saw the first couple of 'yes!' answers, but... *shrugs* @Pabuc, I don't think that's the intent. I just think their first thought (like mine, in the other question) was 'yes! It's easy, we just chain these together...' and then realised that **doesn't** quite work as intended. It'll take a moment, or two. Have patience! =)

Comment: @David Oh these *"Is it possible?"* questions are quite common, I stumble upon them every now and then. And they are usually accompanied by at least one "Yes!" comment. `:)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sure it is... [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/demos/) is good for complex behaviors like drag and drop, resizing, selection and sorting.

With jQuery UI you can:

- Drag
- Drop
- Resize
- Sort

And you can everything chain together.

**It is important for the resize feature that you include the `jquery-ui.css` file.**

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/uQWRk/

Here is the full code for archive:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"/>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#dragThis').resizable({
            stop: function(event, ui) {
                var w = $(this).width();
                var h = $(this).height();
                console.log('StopEvent fired')
                console.log('Width:'+w);
                console.log('Height:'+h)    
            }
        }).draggable(
            {
                containment: $('body'),
                drag: function(){
                    var offset = $(this).offset();
                    var xPos = offset.left;
                    var yPos = offset.top;
                    $('#posX').text('x: ' + xPos);
                    $('#posY').text('y: ' + yPos);
                },
                stop: function(){
                    var finalOffset = $(this).offset();
                    var finalxPos = finalOffset.left;
                    var finalyPos = finalOffset.top;

            $('#finalX').text('Final X: ' + finalxPos);
            $('#finalY').text('Final X: ' + finalyPos);
                }
            });

        $('#dropHere').droppable(
            {
                accept: '#dragThis',
                over : function(){
                    $(this).animate({'border-width' : '5px',
                                     'border-color' : '#0f0'
                                    }, 500);
                    $('#dragThis').draggable('option','containment',$(this));
                }
            });
    });

</script>   
<style type="text/css">
    #dragThis {
        width: 6em;
        height: 6em;
        padding: 0.5em;
        border: 3px solid #ccc;
        border-radius: 0 1em 1em 1em;
        background-color: #fff;
        background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
    }

    #dropHere {
        width: 12em;
        height: 12em;
        padding: 0.5em;
        border: 3px solid #f90;
        border-radius: 1em;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="dragThis">
<ul>
    <li id="posX"></li>
    <li id="posY"></li>
    <li id="finalX"></li>
    <li id="finalY"></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div id="dropHere"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

See comments:
[image]

Comment: Can you tell me how the make the draggable object on http://www.jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/DGbT3/1/ also resizable and get the size of it?

Comment: Yes i can. Give me a second to figure it out.

Comment: That's pretty cool. Um, I've not looked closely at *why*, but on the `draggable`'s `resize` event the `droppable` jumps a little. Using `appendTo()` or something similar?

Comment: Can't understand what are you mean. Everything works as i expected. No jumps here... Maybe it is a browser or css issue in your case.

Comment: That is great. Can you point me how to get/set the size of the object.

Comment: I figured it out. It jumps because on page load the dragThis Div has position:static. But if you resize it it becomes position:absolute and lost his document flow. Add `position: absolute;` would prevent Jumping.

Comment: Well, in Chrome 8 on Ubuntu 10.10, resizing the `draggable` div causes the `droppable` div to jump. I' assuming it's because the `draggable`'s being `position: absolute;`-d, maybe?

Comment: @David Thomas Exactly! @Papuc Just ask the dragThis div:                   `var height = $(this).height(); var width = $(this).width();`

Comment: @gearsdigital, that's kind of implemented in the most-recent edit on my answer to the other question. [JS Fiddle link](http://www.jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/DGbT3/3/). I just couldn't, for the life of me, think how to incorporate `resizable` as well. To my eternal shame... XD

Comment: @gearsdigital - Resize:Stop function isn't triggered. I need to move the object to get the width-height. I guess stop is common for both resize and draggable. How can I make it fire for both events?

Comment: Sure it is... :) You need to config the resizeable(). See my update: http://gearsdigital.com/sandbox/ui/ Note the Firebug Console. You will see once resizing is stopped a message appears width the element Width value and element height value. Take a look at the source.

Comment: I don't see the width and height on stop. Is it just me? :(

Comment: Dont no what you mean. See my update above... Maybe you are not familar with Firebug or i did not understand you correctly.

Comment: I get it now :) I'll start another question. Hope you can help me with that one too :) thank you for your great help.

Comment: See the the code update above. Should work... you need just to work with the data.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4904266/resize-draggable-objects-background-image-on-resize

Answer (score 0):

If you mean draggable, that something like this:

```
$( "#elem" ).resizable().draggable();
```

Size and position you can point with css (first time).
Than you can change them and get (when you resize or move) with jQuery.

You can add options to draggable() and resizable() methods. Reference is here:
http://jqueryui.com/demos/resizable/ and http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/

P.S. This code requires jquery-ui.js file and jquery-ui.css (because it draws a marker to resize)

P.P.S.

With your link:
In JavaScript frame I added the line:

```
$('#dropHere').resizable();
```

And I added css-style in managed resources "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"

And it worked!

Comment: Doesn't work when I add .resizable() to the example http://www.jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/DGbT3/1/

Comment: resizable doesn't work without class="ui-widget-header" and attached css style (of any jquery theme).

Comment: I haven't tried with your link, but in my local example, if I delete <link type="text/css" href="css/flick/jquery-ui-1.8.9.custom.css" rel="stylesheet">  line, than resizable doesn't work.

Comment: I've added class="ui-widget-header" yet it still doesn't work. What else do I have to do? Can you please reference to the link I've gave.

Comment: I'll look. But have you jquery-ui (not just jquery) css file attached?