# Jquery Draggable AND Resizable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-resizable, jquery-ui-draggable

```
function makeResourceDrag(arrIndexID) {

    $('#imgA' + arrIndexID).resizable();

    $('#imgA' + arrIndexID).draggable({
        start: function(event, ui) {
            isDraggingMedia = true;
        },
        stop: function(event, ui) {
            isDraggingMedia = false;

            // Set new x and y
            resourceData[arrIndexID][4] = Math.round($('#imgA' + arrIndexID).position().left / currentScale);
            resourceData[arrIndexID][5] = Math.round($('#imgA' + arrIndexID).position().top / currentScale);

        }
    });

}
```

This works fine if the resizeable line is taken out, but I want these images to be draggable and resizeable, I get funny behaviours if I try and make the same element have both attributes, does anyone know a way to make this work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Looks like it's because you're doing it on an `<img>`, which jqueryui wraps in a `<div>`, and then the draggable component of the image happens within the wrapping `<div>`.

Try wrapping the `<img>` in a `<div>` (which if styled `display:inline-block`, will "hug" the size of the image in both x and y axes), make the `<div>` draggable (and therefore the enclosed `<img>` will be as well), and make the `<img>` resizable (and since the div hugs the image, it all sits nicely).

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/vrUgs/2/

Comment: Thanks davin.  It's a bit more complicated though because the image is attatched to lots of functions and has load() functions as well which makes things a lot harder but your answer + working example is enough for me to go on for now :)

Comment: This was the concise answer i was looking for. After several google pages I happened upon this answer. Thanks!!

Answer (score 10):

Resizable and draggable were causing all kinds of DOM shifting problems for me. There's a [bug filed for this behavior](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/6939); the temporary fix is to apply the following CSS, which worked for me:

```
.element {
  position: absolute !important;
}
```

Comment: This solved my issues in the year 2020. Thanks subelsky.

Answer (score 6):

I was curious, here is working code that is draggable and resizable.
jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(event){
   jQuery(".img").draggable().find("img").resizable();
});
```

html:

```
<div class="img">
  <img alt="" src="images/hard-disk-fingerprint.jpg"/>
</div>
```

other stuff i noticed, take or leave it, as I do not know the work involved in changing your JS.

first, all 'draggables' that are being dragged get a class of '.ui-draggable-dragging'  which, you can use for your 'isDraggingMedia' logic potentially.

second, to get the current position accurately, I recommend using the ui.offset{top:"",left:""}, possible altered with the ui.position{top:"",left:""} describing the position of the 'helper' object relative to the item being dragged.

```
 $('#div holding imgA+arrindexid').draggable({stop:function(event, ui){
//isDraggingMedia = true;  
//replace this with a $().is(ui-draggable-dragging) check if possible where it matters in //your other javascript.
                  // Set new x and y
                    resourceData[arrIndexID][4] = Math.round(ui.offset.left / currentScale);
                    resourceData[arrIndexID][5] = Math.round(ui.offset.top / currentScale);
    }}).find('img').resizable();
```

Comment: @davin definately needs to add the div in front of the image.  i was able to reproduce issues trying to resize and drag on a bare <img>

Answer (score 6):

Make sure `jquery-ui.css` is referenced in your project!

Per this question: [Resizable, draggable object in jquery. Possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4903863/resizable-draggable-object-in-jquery-possible) if you simply include jquery-ui.css it will work.  It solved my problem when none of these did.  My code is simple:

```
$(element).resizable().draggable();
```

This was draggable but not resizable.  Nothing else worked.  Adding the CSS allowed resizing with no extra divs or code.

Comment: including css solved it for me. you might want to highlight that. thanks.

Comment: Updated, hopefully it will help.

Answer (score 2):

If you apply the resizable first, you can then apply the draggable to the img's parent; which is the new div created by applying resizable.

```
chartImg.resizable({ animate: true,
            ghost: true,
            handles: 'n,s,e,w,ne,se,nw,sw',
            start: function (event, ui) { startResize(event, ui); },
            resize: function (event, ui) { monitorResize(event, ui); },
            stop: function (event, ui) { stopResize(event, ui); }
        }).parent().draggable({ containment: $(".chartPane") });
```

Comment: This caused extremely bizarre behavior in my trial.

Comment: This is the solution I ended up going with

Answer (score 0):

The code responsible for this was a workaround for something else: ​[Github link](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/13be9205e1a0d227ef44ab28aed6d0e18aa5cf69/ui/resizable.js#L295-300) which point to [Bug 1749](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/1749).

```
// bugfix for http://dev.jquery.com/ticket/1749
if (el.is('.ui-draggable') || (/absolute/).test(el.css('position'))) {
    el.css({ position: 'absolute', top: iniPos.top, left: iniPos.left });
}
```

The fix itself exists since the beginning of time: ​[Github Bug Fixed link for Jquery](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/commit/ab281b36d7cc10913a77f2f8da9ff7b7c011b3ee#diff-403ec53793e302fe0e3c1ff76b3a8b58R281)

```
// bugfix #1749
if (el.is('.ui-draggable') || (/absolute/).test(el.css('position'))) {

    // sOffset decides if document scrollOffset will be added to the top/left of the resizable element
    var sOffset = $.browser.msie && !o.containment && (/absolute/).test(el.css('position')) && !(/relative/).test(el.parent().css('position'));
    var dscrollt = sOffset ? o.documentScroll.top : 0, dscrolll = sOffset ? o.documentScroll.left : 0;

    el.css({ position: 'absolute', top: (iniPos.top + dscrollt), left: (iniPos.left + dscrolll) });
}
```

And was effectively just updated once, 7 years ago: ​[Updated Link](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/commit/7f12279da59e86c0a0342e7a17b927c53be73697)

```
// bugfix #1749
        // bugfix for http://dev.jquery.com/ticket/1749
        if (el.is('.ui-draggable') || (/absolute/).test(el.css('position'))) {
            // sOffset decides if document scrollOffset will be added to the top/left of the resizable element
            var sOffset = $.browser.msie && !o.containment && (/absolute/).test(el.css('position')) && !(/relative/).test(el.parent().css('position'));
            var dscrollt = sOffset ? this.documentScroll.top : 0, dscrolll = sOffset ? this.documentScroll.left : 0;

            el.css({ position: 'absolute', top: (iniPos.top + dscrollt), left: (iniPos.left + dscrolll) });
            el.css({ position: 'absolute', top: iniPos.top, left: iniPos.left });
        }
```

Reference : [jquery link](https://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/6939#comment:12)