# JQueryUi Draggable - Disable drag changes element transparency

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-resizable

I need to enable/disable the drag and resizable from some images, but when I disable it using `$(".draggable").draggable('disable');` the image seems to have its transparency changed, how can I avoid that?

Here is a JSFiddle to ilustrate my problem:
http://jsfiddle.net/YdWCP/5/

The resizable img is inside a draggable div, because I was having a problem using both interactions on the image and used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4948582/jquery-draggable-and-resizable) solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The transparency is changed because of the jQuery css. You can manually override the opacity attribute. If you simply want to avoid it being transparent.

```
$('.draggable').css('opacity','1');
```

This is your [updated jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/YdWCP/6/)