# drag, clone, and resize after drop with dynamic function in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui

the code below allows me to have 5 different items on a page, and then let me clone any item I drag to different area and allow me to drag the new clone item. However, when I try to move the clone item to different location, it again clone that item. what did i do wrong?

```
<blockquote>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Draggable - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <style>
  #draggable { width: 5px; height: 5px; padding: 0.5em; }
    .arrow h3 { text-align: center; margin: 0; }
  </style>
  <script>
    function DragClone(id) {
        $('.' + id).draggable({helper: "clone"});
        $('.' + id).bind('dragstop', function(event, ui) {
            $(this).after($(ui.helper).clone().draggable());    
        });  
    }

  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="test1" class="i1" onmousedown="DragClone('i1');">
  <img src="img1">
</div>

<div id="test2" class="i2" onmousedown="DragClone('i2');">
  <img src="img2">
</div>

<div id="test3" class="i3" onmousedown="DragClone('i3');">
  <img src="img3">
</div>

<div id="test4" class="i4" onmousedown="DragClone('i4');">
  <img src="img4">
</div>

<div id="test5" class="i5" onmousedown="DragClone('i5');">
  <img src="img5">
</div>




</body>
</html>


</blockquote>
```

if i do, it works fine but i do not want to create 5 the same function with just different class name.

> $(function() {
>             $('.chaser').draggable({helper: "clone"});
>             $('.chaser').bind('dragstop', function(event, ui) {
>                 $(this).after($(ui.helper).clone().draggable());
>             });
>         });

so my main goal is to create one function and pass in the class name so it knows to clone that item only and only clone the original and not the clone. Then allow me to drag the item around and resize the new clone item. please advise. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this will help you, its not perfect i think but quite near [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QW3XD/1/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="test1" class="cloneable" onmousedown="DragClone(this);">
  <img src="img1.png">
</div>
<div id="test2" class="cloneable" onmousedown="DragClone(this);">
  <img src="img2.png">
</div>
```

**JS**

```
DragClone = function(elem) {
    if($(elem).hasClass('cloneable')) {   
      $(elem).draggable({helper: "clone"});
        $(elem).bind('dragstop', function(event, ui) {
           $(this).after($(ui.helper).clone().draggable().removeClass('cloneable'));
           });
        }
    }
```

Update:
I update  [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QW3XD/4/)

Comment: when you first mousedown test1 or test2 object, it will not let you clone or drag. then when you mousedown second time, the clone and drag works fine. Then when you try to drag the clone, it first clone another then function properly.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/QW3XD/3/ its not quite right not sure why it doesn't clone on first mouse down and clone again on drag

Comment: You do not make it draggable at first, that why it does not work on first, it starts working after first mosuedown

Comment: added the   $(function () {
      $('#resizableImage').resizable();
  $('#chase').draggable();
 }); but it is still cloning the object first

Comment: i got it to work the way i wanted it too. with your help of course. however there's one thing left. how do i make the arrow image to resizable in the drag and drop area and not on the original one? here is the fiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/QW3XD/9/

Comment: also when i use css to print the drop area, it doesn't see the new clone items. any ideas?

Comment: should look this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4948582/jquery-draggable-and-resizable and change line var clone =  $(this).after($(ui.helper).clone().draggable().removeClass('cloneable').resizable());