# how to achieve jquery droppable draggable and resizable at the same time

Tags: jquery

can somebody help me to debug my jquery script 
here is my code ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pflores481/c38WX/2/))

```
   // main drop function for work area
      $('#img-drop-container').droppable({
        accept: '.img-drop',

        drop: function(event, ui) {

            var $clone = ui.helper.clone();
            if (!$clone.is('.inside-drop-zone')) {
                $(this).append($clone.addClass('inside-drop-zone').draggable({
                   containment: '#img-drop-container', 
                   stack: '.inside-drop-zone',
                   zIndex: 100, 
                   cursor: 'pointer'                                
                   }));
                  $clone.removeClass('img-drop');

               // resize image
                $('.inside-drop-zone').resizable({
                aspectRatio: true,
                handles: 'ne, se, sw, nw'
                });


 }
 }
});

     //clone the draggable items
    $('li .img-drop').draggable({
        helper: 'clone', 
       cursor: 'pointer',
      });
```

clone image draggable is not working can some fix it?
i want my clone image to be resizable and draggable in id img-drop-container

Comment: in the fiddle the image is resizable, i can resize it.

Comment: the problem is i want the image to be draggable also

Comment: something like this http://jsfiddle.net/pflores481/QTLV6/1/

Comment: [**Look at this**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4948582/2518525)

Comment: resizable and draggable not working in the container at the same time