# Getting CSS value and updating it into SQL

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css

He guys,

I have a div which I make in css like this:

```
echo '#'. $pess2['naam'] .' { width: 190px; height: 90px; padding: 0.5em; float: left; left:'. $pess2['left'] .'px; top:'. $pess2['top'] .'px; visibility:'. $view .'; }'
```

Now when I move that div with:

```
$( "#3" ).draggable({ containment: "#containment-wrapper", scroll: false });
```

I want to upload it to my database.
My question is; how can I get the new left and top (x and y) values in PhP?

Comment: You would need to make a server request. You could use [`$.post`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) or [`$.get`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/), or if you prefer, [`$.ajax`.](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: yep, do you have any server-side script with `UPDATE table SET...` already?

Comment: Yes the query is not the problem, the only problem is how I get the new left and top values in my php variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by Wietse, use stop event(http://jqueryui.com/draggable/#events) to detect when the drag has stopped. In stop event you can use javascript `getBoundingClientRect()` to get the location of DOM element on the screen.

When you have exact coordinates extracted, use your preferred language to post data to server and update database.

I created a fiddle to explain how `.getBoundingClientRect()` works http://jsfiddle.net/B62vM/

Comment: Ok I get all the code, the only problem I have now is that this code doesnt work:

 `stop: function() {
   
   $.post("upload.php", { left: this.getBoundingClientRect().left, top:this.getBoundingClientRect().top })`

It doesnt activate my php file?

Comment: Is jsfiddle link working for you, are you getting alert values after drag ends?

Comment: Yes but I dont need it in a alert I need to send that values to a php file and that is the $.post function right?

Comment: use chrome developer tool and see if you are able to make a network request. If yes, then check for the values getting passed to server.

Comment: Updated fiddle, now it sends a post request with correct parameters. You can use developer tool and test it and modify your server side code accordingly. http://jsfiddle.net/sgaurav/B62vM/1/

Comment: Ok, Ill give it a try

Comment: he says he opens my upload.php but it just doesnt react?
my upload is:

`mysql_query("UPDATE `nvt` SET `left`='". $_POST['left'] ."'")or die(mysql_error());
header("Location: inlogged");
`

Comment: This is totally a different question. Please post it as a separate question and if my answer solved your problem, consider accepting it as correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use the stop event (http://jqueryui.com/draggable/#events), and post the data using $.post() function (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)

To get the position, look here: http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/DGbT3/:

```
$('#dragThis').draggable(
{
    drag: function(){
        var offset = $(this).offset();
        var xPos = offset.left;
        var yPos = offset.top;
        $('#posX').text('x: ' + xPos);
        $('#posY').text('y: ' + yPos);
    }
});
```

(from this question: [How to get the position of a draggable object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4903530/how-to-get-the-position-of-a-draggable-object))

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#takeHiddenVariable").val($("#idOfYourDiv").attr("style"));
```

Use hidden variable in $_POST['takeHiddenVariable'] in your php script.

Answer (score 0):

actually, you could do it mixing previous answers, but with little corrections:

It's not a good idea to use numeric id's, if your `$pess2['naam']` variable is numeric, try something like `echo '#drag'. $pess2['naam'] .'...`, then your jQuery part will be:

```
$('#drag3').draggable({
    containment: "#containment-wrapper", 
    scroll: false
    // use stop here instead of drag to send values only when div stops moving
    stop: function(){
        var offset = $(this).offset();
        // send x and y to your script
        $.post("upload.php", {x: offset.left, y: offset.top});
    }
});
```

On server you will have `$_POST['x']` and `$_POST['y']` variables, that you can use in you SQL  query

```
mysql_query("UPDATE nvt SET left='".$_POST['x']."', top='".$_POST['y']."'")...
```

Here is small example: [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/vladkras/DGbT3/1254/), that sends data and alerts 'updated!' on success. Note that css selector, jQuery selector and div's name must be the same.