# Drag events not firing in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I want to append `div` on dragstop but I cannot see any coordinates getting printed

```
$('.ic_table').on('dragstop', function(e,ui)
    {
        var wrapper = $(this).parent();
        var parentOffset = wrapper.offset(); 
        var relX = parentOffset.left + wrapper.scrollLeft();
        var relY = parentOffset.top + wrapper.scrollTop();
        console.log(relX +" " + relY); //printing 220.75 141 doesn't matter where I drag

//          var editName = "Edit Name";
//          $('#datamodelArea').append('<div id="divDT' + i++ + '" class="dataModelTable ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle style="left:' + relX +'px'+ '; top:' + relY +'px'+';"><div class="dataTableName">'+editName+'</div><div class="widget"><div class="widget-head"> <a href="#" id="toggle1" class="fa fa-chevron-up fa-1x attributes"><i></i></a> Attributes <div class="widget-body attributesBody" id="widget-body1"></div></div></div><div class="widget-body attributesBody" id="widget-body1"><ul></ul></div></div>');
//          $('.form-control').val('');
//      }
    });
```

Comment: Try `dragend` instead of `dragstop`

Comment: Are you sure, that the code is really executed?

Comment: @Lauromine using dragend is printing `NaN NaN`

Comment: @Satyadev So, `dragend` is fine, your problem is elsewhere.

Comment: @Lauromine e.pageX(prints undefined) was the problem. I removed it. Now doesn't matter where I drag, the x and y is always 220.75 141. Is it with css?

Comment: @Lauromine updated the question

Comment: @Satyadev take a look at this, it might help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4903530/how-to-get-the-position-of-a-draggable-object