# How to get dragged position using vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop

Basically I just want to get the position of a dragged element. I have read the previous questions like this one: [How to get the position of a draggable object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4903530/how-to-get-the-position-of-a-draggable-object). But that is based on jQuery. Is there a way to achieve this with pure javascript?

I have tried something like below but doesn't work:

```
itemDrag() {
    let card = document.querySelector("div.draggable");
    let rect = card.getBoundingClientRect();
    console.log(rect.top, rect.right, rect.bottom, rect.left);
}
```

I triggered this with ondrag event. It turns out that although the event is fired multiple times, the rect remains in the original position. Is there a way to handle that?

Comment: There must be something [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=drag+and+drop+javascript+site%3Astackoverflow.com)

Comment: mplungjan, I followed a link here from google. So your link back to google is very unhelpful.